# Apply decorator to context processor

Tags: python, django, facebook, fandjango

I'm using Fandjango for a Django Facebook Canvas app.

To use fandjango, you need to wrap all view functions with `@facebook_authorization_required`, which makes sure you're authorized, then gives you the variable `request.facebook.user`.

**What I want** is to make a context processor which defines a few more variables based on this, i.e., I want all my templates to be able to use `fb_user` as a shortcut for `request.facebook.user`.

**The problem is**, I don't know how to use the decorator on the context processor.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Could `fb_user = request.facebook.user` simply help?

Comment: Yes, I could add that to all views, I just have a few more assignments, and I'd rather not repeat them in every view.

Comment: I mean, just as Daniel's answer, why not write `fb_user = request.facebook.user` in a context_processor directly, w/ some condition checking of course.

Comment: The context processor is invoked in RequestContext(), which usually resides inside your view, thus actually it is *wrapped* by decorator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to wrap the context processor. If you've wrapped the view in the first place, then the `request` will already be annotated with the `facebook.user` attribute. Since the request is passed to the context processor anyway, you have access to that attribute.

You should probably do a quick check - `if hasattr(request, 'facebook')` - within the context processor, just to make sure it's being called from a wrapped view.

Comment: Hmm. That's what I did originally, only it didn't work. I'll recheck, maybe I made some other error.

Comment: OK well I recheked it and it seems to be working. Thinking back, it did work in my early testing, then stopped working. Now I'm unsure whether it's something wrong I added or what exactly is going on.
A possibility - perhaps I unknowingly made a call to an ajax function which does not have the "facebook" in the request, and this  cause errors. I'll try the code with the hasattr check, and see if it comes back.

Comment: OK seems like I understood the issue: in cases where Fandjango needs to recheck facebook to get the user (some kind of authentication or cache refreshing I assume), the first time the view was loaded it did *not* have a Facebook user. Note: I had to do `if hasattr(request.facebook, 'user')`, not what you wrote in your answer.